# iphone how to get timezone?

Tags: iphone, timezone

i want to get timezone but cant.

i use NSLog is show to me is show.time = 2011-06-29 04:20:00 +0000

here is my code.

```
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    //[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
    //[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];



    timedata = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance]; 

    obj.showdate = timedata;

    //NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //[defaults setObject:timedata forKey:@"selectdate"];
    //NSLog(@"save time = %@",obj.showdate);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Where and how do you want to display the time?

Comment: hi,i want display the time is show.time = 2011-06-29 12:28:00 +8000 like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covert NSString to NSDate in a different timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910060/covert-nsstring-to-nsdate-in-a-different-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the time zone for your `NSDateComponents` object to GMT:

```
[dateComps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

Thus your date will be interpreted as being in GMT. If you want the time zone that the device is in, use `systemTimeZone`:

```
[dateComps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

In general, as noted in [the docs for `timeZoneWithAbbreviation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneWithAbbreviation%3a), the abbreviations can be ambiguous. If you want to get a particular time zone in a way that will always work no matter the location of the device, you can use [`timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT%3a).

You can also set a time zone for your app, if you want, rather than always referring to a specific time zone when creating date-related objects:

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:60*8]];
NSTimeZone * appTZ = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```